# Getting fields from extra manager methods using django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following [custom model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods) in Django that is meant to count the number of related comments and add them to the objects query set:

```
class PublicationManager(models.Manager):
    def with_counts(self):
        return self.annotate(
            count_comments=Coalesce(models.Count('comment'), 0)
        )
```

Adding this manager to the model does not automatically add the extra field in DRF. In my API view, I found a way to retrieve the `count_comments` field by overriding the get function such as:

```
class PublicationDetails(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Publication.objects.with_counts()
    ...

    def get(self, request, pk):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset.get(id=pk))
        
        data = {**serializer.data}
        data['count_comments'] = queryset.get(id=pk).count_comments
        return Response(data)
```

This works for a single instance, but when I try to apply this to a paginated list view using `pagination_class`, overriding the get method seems to remove pagination functionality (i.e. I get a list of results instead of the usual page object with previous, next, etc.). This leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong: should I be adding the custom manager's extra field to the serializer instead? I'm not sure how to proceed given that I'm using a model serializer. Should I be using a basic serializer?

Answer (score 0):

## Update

As it turns out, I was using the model manager all wrong. I didn't understand the idea of table-level functionality when what I really wanted was row-level functionality to count the number of comments related to a single instance. I am now using a custom `get_paginated_response` method with `Comment.objects.filter(publication=publication).count()`.

## Original answer

I ended up solving this problem by creating a custom pagination class and overriding the `get_paginated_response` method.

```
class PaginationPublication(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        for item in data:
            publication = Publication.objects.with_counts().get(id=item['id'])
            item['count_comments'] = publication.count_comments

        return super().get_paginated_response(data)
```

Not sure it's the most efficient solution, but it works!